# How to continue an enumeration?

Tags: lists, enumerate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list)

What is the best way to extend an enumeration such that the next enumeration environment does not start with one but with the number following the last item from the previous enumeration? (Let's ignore the problem of nested `enumerate` environments.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item One
    \item Two    
    \end{enumerate}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod. 

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Three
    \item Four     
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

#### This is a Duplicate

See [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1669/215).

Answer (score 34):

This solution doesn't use any package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  It is possible to save the contents of \texttt{enumi} at the end of an enumeration:
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is an item.
    \item This is another item. We will now stop the enumeration.
    \newcounter{enumTemp}
    \setcounter{enumTemp}{\theenumi}
  \end{enumerate}
  \texttt{enumTemp} is now \theenumTemp. We can continue the enumeration like so:
  \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{\theenumTemp}
    \item The list goes on
    \item and on.
  \end{enumerate}
  You can also put everything into your own macros for convenience. Note that this is a bit hackish, but it works.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hat to do `\setcounter{enumi}{\value{theenumTemp}}` or I would get an `Undefined control sequence` error.

Comment: What is so bad about using additional packages?

Comment: Adding enumitem messes up a beamer document. It's good to have different solutions.

Answer (score 33):

Try to uncommment the second section.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \section{Hahaha}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First 
      \item Second 
    \end{enumerate}
  %\section{Hihihi}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume] % to resume
      \item Third 
      \item Fourth 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```