# How to have the same counter in two enumerate lists?

Tags: lists, enumerate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list)

I want to have an enumerate list which is broken in the middle by some text. What I have at the moment is something along the lines of this,

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{theorem} We are in the theorem environment,
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{condition1}the first condition,
    \item\label{condition2}the second condition,
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

We have exited the theorem environment. We also have one more condition,

\begin{enumerate}
  \item[\emph{(iii)}]\label{condition3}\emph{the third condition}.
\end{enumerate}
```

However, I do not like the fact I have to manually number the final condition, and it also leaves me with problems when referencing. I was therefore wondering if it is possible to connect the counters in the two lists?

Otherwise (and clearly this is less than ideal), is there a way of getting \ref{condition2} to be (iii) (that is, what it is in the square brackets). There must be some way of doing this, but I cannot find it! Currently, it spits out...2 (so clearly my issues go deeper than just this question! However, a solution to one of these question would pretty much sort everything out...).

> EDIT

The solutions given in the [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list) question do not seem to work in my example. Two solutions were proffered:

The second solution, which gets LaTeX to save the counter manually, I cannot get to work in my document, although it does work when I make a sample document. This is similar to the answer given below, which *does* work in my document, so I will not dwell on this.

The first solution has a subtle problem, which makes it unsuitable for my use. This solution uses the enumitem package. The solution works if the document contains only one Theorem, or if both lists are not straddling a theorem in any way. However, the following does not work (and this most closely resembles what I am doing),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} We are in the theorem environment,
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{condition1}the first condition,
    \item \label{condition2}the second condition,
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

We havve exited the theorem environment. We also have one more condition,
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item \label{condition3}\emph{the third condition}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{theorem}
  We have another theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Here, the counter is reset when we exit the theorem environment so we get,

```
(i) the third condition.
```

while we actually want

```
(iii) the third condition.
```

and the same thing happens to the reference (the code I've got above will give `\ref{condition3}` as `1`)

Comment: The enumitem package doesn't seem to like more than one counter going on. If I am not in the theorem environment then I have no problems, but because one list is in the theorem environment and the other is outside the counter is (seemingly) reset (however, if you have a document with only one theorem there is no problems).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can save and restore the count like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\saveenum{\xdef\@savedenum{\the\c@enumi\relax}}
\def\resetenum{\global\c@enumi\@savedenum}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{theorem}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} We are in the theorem environment,
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{condition1}the first condition,
\item\label{condition2}the second condition,
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

We have exited the theorem environment. We also have one more condition,

\saveenum
\begin{enumerate}\resetenum
\item\label{condition3}\emph{the third condition}.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```