# how to create enumeration spanning multiple paragraphs?

Tags: lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list)

i want to create a list which has arbitrary sized paragraphs in between:

[image: screenshot of document as it should look like]

How can i do this? (what i have now is done with centering and there is no automatic numbering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\a{One two three. }
\def\b{\a\a Four five. \a}
\def\c{\b\b Red green blue. \b \a}
\def\d{\c\c}

\newcounter{hyp}

\newenvironment{hyp}
{\refstepcounter{hyp}\trivlist\itshape\centering\item[(\thehyp)]}
{\endtrivlist}


\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}\label{ha}
Something or other is better than that other thing
\end{hyp}

Some text about hypothesis \ref{ha} \d


\begin{hyp}\label{hb}
Black and white.
\end{hyp}

Some text about hypothesis \ref{hb} \d


\end{document}
```