# Shared counter (between description environments) results in "undefined control sequence"

Tags: errors, environments, counters, description

The objective is to share the counter `SharedCTR1` across the description environments. The following code works with only one description environment, but not with both.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

{\newcounter{SharedCTR}
\def\SharedCTR1{\stepcounter{SharedCTR}\arabic{SharedCTR}}

\section{Section one}

\begin{description}
  \item[desc \SharedCTR1.] text text.
  \item[desc \SharedCTR1.] text text text.
  \item[desc \SharedCTR1.] text text text text.
\end{description}                                %% In original doc: extra curly bracket was here.


\section{Section two}

\begin{description}
  \item[desc \myUseCaseCTR1.] text text.          % Fails on this line.
  \item[desc \myUseCaseCTR1.] text text text.
  \item[desc \myUseCaseCTR1.] text text text text.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

I first thought the problem was the number `1` in the name but it still won't work if I remove it.
The error is the following:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> desc \myUseCaseCTR 
                              1.
l.20   \item[desc \myUseCaseCTR1.]
                                   text text.          % Fails on this line.
```

---

[edit] In the original (long) document it was written, at some point, `\end{description}}`. There was an extra curly bracket `}` which was causing the error a few lines later when the variable was being used again in a different description environment. It took me awhile to spot the problem.

Comment: Adding `\setcounter{SharedCTR}{\arabic{SharedCTR}}` at the end of the first description environment does not help either. It seems redundant but there was something similar at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list.

Comment: Where is `\myUseCaseCTR1` counter defined?

Comment: I am wondering what you want to achieve? Shall the counter be reset when a new `description` environment starts. Wouldn't an `enumerate` environment suffice or the resume option of `enumitem` package list environments, as you already have linked to in your previous comment?

Comment: Don't use `\def\SharedCTR1{...}` to begin with; the digit will not be part of the name, but of the parameter text. In any case, you can't use `\myUseCaseCTR` without having defined it.

Comment: @Ignasi: `\myUseCaseCTR1` is supposed to be `\SharedCTR1`. I renamed it since I wanted to provide a simpler version of the real document to analyze the problem (too long to paste it all here) and this variable name seemed more appropriate. However, I forgot to rename it on the second section and once I did it worked just fine which is rather embarrassing.

Comment: As you can see the error message says `Undefined control sequence` and stops on `\myUseCaseCTR` because `\myUseCaseCTR` is undefined. Therefore, until you don't define `\myUseCaseCTR` this error will remain. You can also see like `1` is not considered part of `\myUseCaseCTR` name.

Comment: I've both redefined the name and removed the digit in my document. On a side note, on the original document the variable name was the same although I still had the digit. The reason it was not working was a misplaced `}` a few lines before the actual error. I've added a note to the question for future reference.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo (and a missing definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted an extra `{`, but that wasn't the major problem. You haven't defined the second definition (`\myUseCaseCTR`) if you check it closely, the name is different from (`\SharedCTR`). I have used the `\let` command to define it, see line number 7.

I enclose a working example and a preview.

```
\documentclass{report}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
%{ % Deleted
\newcounter{SharedCTR}
\def\SharedCTR1{\stepcounter{SharedCTR}\arabic{SharedCTR}}
\let\myUseCaseCTR=\SharedCTR
\section{Section one}
\begin{description}
  \item[desc \SharedCTR1.] text text.
  \item[desc \SharedCTR1.] text text text.
  \item[desc \SharedCTR1.] text text text text.
\end{description}
\section{Section two}
\begin{description}
  \item[desc \myUseCaseCTR1.] text text. % Failed on this line.
  \item[desc \myUseCaseCTR1.] text text text.
  \item[desc \myUseCaseCTR1.] text text text text.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose, that the `\let\myUseCaseCTR` statement is not necessary at all, since in my point of view, there is no need of referring to the original command `\SharedCTR1` when it is not redefined at all.

Comment: It's hard to say what are the author's next plans. I tried not to touch the original source code. Yes, replacing all `myUseCase` with `Shared` is also an option.

Comment: Yes, it's sometimes a guess what is intended next  ;-)

Comment: Uh-oh, the idea was to use `\SharedCTR1` in both places. I forgot to rename the second one when I changed the name before posting here.