# Table of equations like list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am fairly new at this and trying to put a table containing a brief description of the equations I use, into my thesis. This has proven to be quite an irritating problem. I have found a nice concise solution on the web (http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=428) which has been very helpful (thanks to  gmedina). The solution uses the tocloft package to define a new list.

The problem I now have, is that as the equation numbers get longer the text description and equation numbers overlap, can anyone help me with this? Also if anyone can explain the command clearly it be very helpful. Below is a MWE I am using texmaker and Miktex.

```
 %%Preamble
 \documentclass[12pt]{report}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{tocloft}
 \usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}

 %%gmedina solution
 \newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
 \newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
 \newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
 \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}

\begin{document}

\listofmyequations

\chapter{sums}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.1}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.2}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.3}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.4}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.5}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.6}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.7}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.8}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.9}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.10}
\myequations{sum}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) provides `\cft<set>numwidth` for the width of the number associated with an entry `<set>`. In your case, `<set>` is `myequations`, so we can adjust `\cftmyequationsnumwidth` in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

%%gmedina solution
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}% Width of equation number in List of Equations

\begin{document}

\listofmyequations

\chapter{sums}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.1}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.2}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.3}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.4}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.5}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.6}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.7}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.8}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.9}
\myequations{sum}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2.10}
\myequations{sum}

\end{document}
```

I used `2.5em`, where the default is usually `1.5em`.

Answer (score 7):

I expanded upon the previous answer to define a command that you can use like so:

```
\noteworthy{a^2 + b^2 = c^2}{Pythagorean theorem}
```

And it will automatically label, reference, box, and list the equations that I consider noteworthy. I'm really happy with the result.

Note that the red squares just highlight hyperlinks, they're not visible on the pdf.

[image]

And then the equation is numbered, boxed, labelled with text (that matches the list of equations), and gets a label to allow us to reference it.

[image]

Minimum viable example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}    % for list of equations
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % to undo \centering
\usepackage{hyperref}   % to make references hyperlinks
\usepackage{glossaries} 

% define list of equations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{\Large{List of Equations}}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{
   \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}
}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}

% command to box, label, reference, and 
% include noteworthy equation in list of equations
\newcommand{\noteworthy}[2]{
\begin{align} \label{#2} \ensuremath{\boxed{#1}} \end{align} 
\myequations{#2} \centering \small \textit{#2} \normalsize \justify }

\begin{document}

\listofmyequations \pagebreak

\noteworthy{P(\bigcup_{n=1}^n A_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^n P(A_n)}{Boole's inequality}

Where the events $A_n$ are disjoint, then the inequality 
in equation \ref{Boole's inequality} becomes an equality.

\end{document}
```

Demo: https://www.overleaf.com/read/vftqrxghqchv

Comment: This snippets augments the accepted solution with the missing indentation nicely.

Comment: DM from an SO user: "Your solution worked very well for me but when the formula was in an item in an enumerated list, it appeared to break the list.  The items after \noteworthy were no longer numbered.  I got around the problem by using the idea shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list .  If I ended the enumerated list right before the \noteworthy formula, I could then resume the list with the next item after \noteworthy.  A little bit of extra trouble, but well worth it to me for the result."

Comment: \noteworthy is **Excellent!** I use it for **ALL** my equations ... Is there a way to include the list of the \noteworthy equations in the **TOC** with a heading of "**Table of Equations**"? Thanks!

Comment: I have both a "**List of Equations**" and a "**Table of Equations**" for my **noteworthy** equations that print out beautifully just before my **Bibliography** at the end of my project. However, both the **LoE** and **ToE** are not listed in my main **TOC**. Apologies for my limited **LaTeX** knowledge, but what am I missing? Is there a way to have an entry in my main **TOC** that indicates the initial page(s) for my **LoE** and **ToE** the same way my **TOC** indicates the initial page number for my **Bibliography**?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), which provides:

> ```
> \AfterEndEnvironment{〈environment〉}{〈code〉}
> ```
>
> Appends arbitrary〈code〉to a hook executed at a very late point by the \endcommand, after the group holding the environment has been closed.

You can then put

```
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\myequations{}}
```

in your preamble and every time you use the equation environment (and only the equation environment, so for align etc. you'd need to duplicate the above and use align instead of equation) it will add the usage of said environment to the list generated by the other answers.

This also means the starred variant of the environment will not appear in the list.