# List of Equations with tocloft not created with Pandoc

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, pandoc

I want to create a list of Equations in my thesis and have used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173102/193336) to create my own version for use with pandoc:

```
---
header-includes: |
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
---
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\listofmyequations
\newpage

\begin{equation}
f_d = \frac{2 \cdot v \cdot f_O}{c}
\end{equation}
\label{eq:Frequenzverschiebung}
\myequations{Frequenzverschiebung}


\begin{equation}
v= f_d \cdot \frac{c}{2*f_O} 
\end{equation}
\label{eq:geschwindigkeit}
\myequations{Geschwindigkeit}
```

i build it with this command:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$PATH:/home/moritz/.cabal/bin/ /home/moritz/.cabal/bin/pandoc --filter pandoc-citeproc --bibliography quellen.bib --csl=styles/din1505.csl --filter pandoc-include-code -V hyphens=URL -V breakurl --from=markdown --output=text.pdf  text.md \
```

this is producing this:

[image: no list of equations]

As you can see there is no list created.

I have tried to create the MWE provided by the post mentioned above and this is working correctly when compiling from .tex to pdf with pdflatex, so I guess the problem is in combination with pandoc.