# List of Equation with tocloft is displayed incorrectly

Tags: equations, tocloft

I would like to make a list of equation and found this post 
[List of equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173102/table-of-equations-like-list-of-figures). That's what i want but I have the problem that my list does not look like the lof or lot. My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3.2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newlistof{equations}{equ}{\listequationsname}

\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}

\begin{document}
    \listofequations

    \begin{equation}
    Z = 1
    \end{equation}
\myequations{A simple equation}

\end{document}
```

My Output looks like this:
[image]

What is the Problem? How can I correct it?

Comment: You need to change `myequations` to `equations` in the `\addcontentsline` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the names. However, your placement of `\myequations` is wrong. I'd call it `\eqdesc` (personal preference) and place it *inside* the equation, because it's where it belongs.

Also, you can use it in `align` and make it to cooperate with `hyperref`, which is a good reason for use such a list.

As the code is written, it's not relevant whether you load `hyperref` or not.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newlistof{equations}{equ}{\listequationsname}

\newcommand{\eqdesc}[1]{%
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname % if hyperref is loaded
  \addcontentsline{equ}{equations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\listofequations

\clearpage

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{equation}
Z = 1
\eqdesc{A simple equation}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3][1-2]
\begin{align}
a &= 1 \eqdesc{Another equation} \\
b &= 2 \eqdesc{Yet another one}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly.

Comment: This is wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

You took the code from [Werners answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173104/29873) and changed the name of the list from `myequations` to `equations` but forgot to change it in the `\addcontentsline` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3.2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newlistof{equations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{equations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}


\begin{document}
  \listofequations

  \begin{equation}
    Z = 1
  \end{equation}
  \myequations{A simple equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]