# How do I reset the equation counter in a tcolorbox align environment?

Tags: align, tcolorbox, counters

After poring over this site and the `tcolorbox` documentation for over an hour, I can't figure out how to reset the equation counter inside my `derivation` environment. I wrote the old version with `mdframed` and there it was as simple as `\setcounter{equation}{0}` at the beginning of the environment, but that obviously doesn't work here. I need the numbering to start over with each instance of `derivation`. I have a feeling it's trivial and I'm just not seeing it.

My MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{derivation}{%
  ams align,%
  title={DERIVATION \thetcbcounter},%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,%
  label={derivation@\thetcbcounter},
  coltitle=black,%
  colback=orange!25,%
  colframe=orange!60%
  %colback=orange!5!white,%
  %colframe=orange!75!black%
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{derivation}
  x + y &= z     && \text{given} \\
      y &= z - x && \text{solve for \(y\)}
\end{derivation}
\begin{derivation}
  \gamma &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}      && \text{definition} \\
       v &= \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}} && \text{solve for \(v\)}
\end{derivation}
\end{document}
```

MWE output:
[image: MWE Output]

Comment: You *can* use the `mdframed` method here, just add `code=\setcounter{equation}{0}` to the options of the `derivation` box. The question is whether this makes sense because then different equations carry the same number.

Comment: That works! Thank you. Can't find it in the `tcolorbox` docs. I can't imagine seeing derivations in a math or physics textbook with consecutively numbered steps through the book. The individual steps won't be referenced, only the boxes themselves. Am I missing something?

Comment: I personally would prefer something of the sort `(<number of derivation>-<number of equation in>)` derivation, which can be achieved with `code=\setcounter{equation}{0}\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thetcbcounter-\arabic{equation}}`. This is still not too good if you have ordinary equations in the document, but you could memorize the orginal equation number and restore it after the box in that case. BTW, the `code` key can be found in section **4.24 Miscellaneous** of the tcolorbox manual v4.42.

Comment: Hey I like that! Make that an answer and I'll accept it. Yep I finally found `code` in the docs. Well hidden! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various hooks that allow one to execute some code at various stages of the construction of the box. The following uses `code` and `after`. It also redefines and restores equation numbering, similar to the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184637/227987). Note, however, that I do not want to make the impression that this is a super stable solution. I did not check whether this works with hyperref, nor did I do other cross-checks. Yet a conceivably more stable solution, which may or may not make use of future versions of the LaTeX kernel, may possibly use the same keys as in this code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newcounter{savedeq}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{derivation}{%
  code=\setcounter{savedeq}{\value{equation}}%
    \setcounter{equation}{0}\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thetcbcounter-\arabic{equation}},%
  after=\setcounter{equation}{\value{savedeq}},%
  ams align,%
  title={DERIVATION \thetcbcounter},%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,%
  label={derivation@\thetcbcounter},
  coltitle=black,%
  colback=orange!25,%
  colframe=orange!60,%
  %colback=orange!5!white,%
  %colframe=orange!75!black%
}%
%\numberwithin{equation}{derivation}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\begin{derivation}
  x + y &= z     && \text{given} \\
      y &= z - x && \text{solve for \(y\)}
\end{derivation}
\begin{equation}
E=h\nu
\end{equation}
\begin{derivation}
  \gamma &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}      && \text{definition} \\
       v &= \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}} && \text{solve for \(v\)}
\end{derivation}
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to work fine. If I add `list inside=deriv` to the `init` for `derivation` and put `\tcblistof{deriv}{List of Derivations}` just after `\begin{document}` everything looks fine. Then if I `\usepackage{hyperref}` I get warnings about `ignoring duplicate destination`. Aside from that, it works.

Comment: Setting the `naturalnames=true` option when loading `hyperref` seems to correct the issue.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL Thanks for letting me know! This seems to be indeed a bit more "natural than" the posts I have linked to.

Comment: I didn't initially plan to implement links to derivation steps, but I think students will find it useful. Plus, I'm trying to combine this solution with the one found here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547806/218142. Let's see just how much I can break things!