# How to...list of formulas

Tags: lists, indexing, thesis

I am writing my engineering thesis.
I would need a list of the formulas (just like that of the figures and tables). I would also like to include it in the index.
How can I do?

Thanks so much.

Comment: [Table of equations like list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173102/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your needs. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``