# Adjust parameters of resumed lists

Tags: spacing, enumitem

When an [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) list is resumed there is some additional vertical space that is applied as can be seen in the difference in the vertical alignment of the 2nd item:

[image]

I assume this is related to `topsep`. So, I could adjust the `topsep` parameter manually each time I resume a list, but wondering if there is a way to define the `MyEnumerate` list so that the values of `topsep` (and perhaps any others things that need tweaking) are different for resumed lists vs. the initial (non-resumed) list.

Also, what is the correct mathematical computation of the `topsep` value required in terms of the other `enumitem` spacing parameters?

### References:

- [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{MyEnumerate}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[MyEnumerate]{label*=(\arabic*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    My List of items:
    \begin{MyEnumerate}
        \item First Item.
        \item Second Item.
        \item Third Item.
        \item Fourth Item.
    \end{MyEnumerate}%
    End of list.
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    My List of items:
    \begin{MyEnumerate}[series=foo]
        \item First Item.
    \end{MyEnumerate}
    \begin{MyEnumerate}[resume*=foo]
        \item Second Item (resumed).
    \end{MyEnumerate}%
    \begin{MyEnumerate}[resume*=foo]
        \item Third Item (resumed).
    \end{MyEnumerate}%
    \begin{MyEnumerate}[resume*=foo]
        \item Fourth Item (resumed).
    \end{MyEnumerate}%
    End of resumed list.
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The gap is actually `\topsep+\parskip`. If you place `\vspace{\dimexpr-\topsep-\parskip}` as the first thing inside `MyEnumerate`, the two align vertically.

Comment: @Werner: Indeed, that works if I place them in _every resumed_ list (but not the initial list). Now, can I apply that when I apply a `resume`?

Comment: note that you get the same spacing even when you remove the `resume` stuff

Comment: @cmhughes: Yep. But a new list will be proceeded by text so that is ok.  So, I guess I could set something like `itemsep=\dimexpr\topsep+\parskip` (not quite right), but I'd prefer to leave the new list spacing as is, just tweak the resumed list spacing to match.

Comment: @PeterGrill: The instance you show may be very particular, as you're actually using a list setup in 4 separate lists while representing a single list. It may be possible to patch the `resume` key to also adjust the `topsep` key, I think.

Comment: @Werner: Or perhaps defining a new key `Resume` instead so that other `resume`s are not affected. Don't think I need that, but just in case.

Comment: Curiosity... Why do you want to do this? If there is no text in between, why not just continue the list? If there is text, you want the separation... I'd assumed this was meant to be used when non-list stuff intervenes. At least, that's how I've used it and I definitely *want* the same vertical spacing in that case.

Comment: @cfr: I guess that is one of the problems with a MWE in that the actual context gets lost. The reason I need this is that items are conditional so may not get typeset, and it is possible that the entire list is not typeset at all.  This simplest way to do that seemed to me to use the `resume` feature.  I removed that portion of the MWE as it did not seem to be needed.

Comment: In which case my answer is not only uncool but won't work, I think. Should I delete it?

Comment: @cfr No need to delete it. It does work for the MWE as posted and I might end up adapting that if a solution that provides a new key such as `Resume` doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a new environment for resuming the list. This isn't as cool as defining a new `Resume` key or redefining `resume` but...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{MyEnumerate}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[MyEnumerate]{label*=(\arabic*)}
\newenvironment{MyResume}[1]{%
  \begin{MyEnumerate}[resume*=#1,topsep=\itemsep,partopsep=\parsep]}{%
  \end{MyEnumerate}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    My List of items:
    \begin{MyEnumerate}
        \item First Item.
        \item Second Item.
        \item Third Item.
        \item Fourth Item.
    \end{MyEnumerate}%
    End of list.
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    My List of items:
    \begin{MyEnumerate}[series=foo]
        \item First Item.
    \end{MyEnumerate}
    \begin{MyResume}{foo}
        \item Second Item (resumed).
    \end{MyResume}%
    \begin{MyResume}{foo}
        \item Third Item (resumed).
    \end{MyResume}%
    \begin{MyResume}{foo}
        \item Fourth Item (resumed).
    \end{MyResume}%
    End of resumed list.
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

[image: Resumed list]