# How to modify enumeration counter?

Tags: enumerate

I would like to enumerate axiom like this in my document.

```
A1 this is the first axiom
A2 this is the second axiom

Now some text

A3 this is the third axiom
```

How can I do it in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

axioms and similar elements are usually handled as theorem environments, which are
automatically numbered.
using this approach, you can, in your preamble, include this directive:

```
\newtheorem{axiom}{A}
```

this will label the axioms as "A 1", "A 2", etc.

(it's more usual to spell out "Axiom"; that would replace the "A" in the above code.)

if you really want the labeling to be "A1", etc., with no space between "A" and the
number, things get more complicated.  please confirm this requirement, as well as
specifying the document class you are using and any packages, so that the appropriate
code can be provided.

Comment: This is fine answer and suitable for my document. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard to to have no space between A and the axiom number:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{axiom}{axiom}{axioms}
\Crefname{axiom}{Axiom}{Axioms}

\newtheorem{axiom}{}
\renewcommand\theaxiom{A\arabic{axiom}}

\begin{document}

\begin{axiom}\label{ax1}
This is the first axiom.
\end{axiom}

\begin{axiom}\label{ax2}
This is the second axiom.
\end{axiom}
\Cref{ax2} cannot be deduced from \cref{ax2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]