# Resuming a list (for nested lists)

Tags: enumerate, counters

I'm trying to resume a list by storing and restoring the counter. This works fine (as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list)), but I fail to do it for a nested list. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

  \newcounter{stoppedhere}

%   \begin{enumerate}      % <- outer list commented out
%     \item Outer list

    \begin{multicols}{3}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item $e$
        \item $\gamma$
        \item $\mu$
        \item $p$
        \item $n$
        \item $\pi^+$
        \item $\pi^0$
        \item $\nu_\mu$
        \setcounter{stoppedhere}{\theenumi}
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \setcounter{enumi}{\thestoppedhere}
      \item much longer item 1
      \item another much longer item
    \end{enumerate}

%   \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The code above first lists 1. - 9. and then continues with 10., so that works.

Now if I add back the outer list, the resumed list starts with the wrong value (as expected). I thought I could solve this by using `enumii`, but trying to do

```
\setcounter{stoppedhere}{\theenumii}
```

gives an error (`! Missing number, treated as zero.`). What need I do instead?

(The `multicol` environment is not part of the problem, unless I try to use the package `enumitem` instead of modifying the counters myself: then it only works without the `multicol` environment.)

Comment: Use `enumitem`. Then you can use `resume` to continue an enumerated list.

Comment: @cfr: I thought that too, but the `multicols` environment does indeed work badly here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't think it is really `multicols` fault....

Comment: @cfr: No, it's rather a grouping/nesting problem. Apparently `enumitem` loses the track which nesting level was valid

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways:

1. Use the counter method with `enumitem` and manually add a `start=...` to the next enumeration
2. Use the `enumitem` package and define the inner list as a series `innerlist` (the name is rather arbitrary`) and use`resume=innerlist`in the continued (outside of`multicols` environment) list. This is the better way, in my point of view (see example at the bottom of this post)

**Note**: `\theenumi` should not be used as argument to `\setcounter`, since `\theenumi` could be defined to be anything, letters, brackets with letters, numbers etc. Use `\value{enumi}` for a pure number.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{stoppedhere}

\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}      % <- outer list commented out
     \item Outer list
       \begin{multicols}{3}
         \begin{enumerate}
         \item $e$
         \item $\gamma$
         \item $\mu$
         \item $p$
         \item $n$
         \item $\pi^+$
         \item $\pi^0$
         \item $\nu_\mu$
           \setcounter{stoppedhere}{\value{enumii}}
         \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \begin{enumerate}[start=\numexpr\number\value{stoppedhere}+1]
      \item much longer item 1
      \item another much longer item
    \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Other approach: (Better!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}      % <- outer list commented out
     \item Outer list
       \begin{multicols}{3}
         \begin{enumerate}[series=innerlist]
         \item $e$
         \item $\gamma$
         \item $\mu$
         \item $p$
         \item $n$
         \item $\pi^+$
         \item $\pi^0$
         \item $\nu_\mu$
         \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume=innerlist]
      \item much longer item 1
      \item another much longer item
    \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might add the explanation: `\theenumii` produces a letter rather than a number.

Comment: @cfr: I am about completing the answer ... just be patient ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this was the hint I needed. It works by just adding the `\value` macro. (The `series` thing didn't work for me, maybe my version of the `enumitem` package is too old.)

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig: Yes, it works with the counter way, but I don't recommend it. You should update `enumitem`. It's a very powerful package!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution without `enumitem`. `\theenumii` does not produce a number so you cannot use it to set the counter. Instead, you need to use `\value{enumii}` which always gives the value of the counter i.e. as a number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

  \newcounter{stoppedhere}

  \begin{enumerate}      % <- outer list commented out
    \item Outer list

    \begin{multicols}{3}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item $e$
        \item $\gamma$
        \item $\mu$
        \item $p$
        \item $n$
        \item $\pi^+$
        \item $\pi^0$
        \item $\nu_\mu$
        \setcounter{stoppedhere}{\value{enumii}}
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \setcounter{enumii}{\thestoppedhere}
      \item much longer item 1
      \item another much longer item
    \end{enumerate}

  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: inner and outer]

Comment: That's what I ended up using.