# Resuming a list in lyx

Tags: lyx, enumerate

I have the same question as this one, but for lyx

[Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, go to Document --> Settings --> Modules, add the *Customisable lists (enumitem)* module:

[image]

### For LyX 2.3+

After adding the module, you can use the *Enumerate-Resume* layout. This will resume previous enumerations, if they exist, both in LyX and the output document.

[image]

### Alternatively

Write the two lists with text between them, and to add the `[resume]` option, right click the *first* entry in the second list, and choose *Enumerate options* (shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>):

[image]

In the inset that shows up, type `resume`:

[image]

LyX and output:

[image]

Comment: After adding the module, you can also use the "Enumerate-resume" environment. In LyX 2.3.0 (but not before), if you do it that way LyX will also display the correct number (e.g. in the example above "Fourth" will be prefixed with a "4." instead of a "1.").

Comment: @scottkosty thanks the "enumerate-resume" environment works and resumes numbering in the compiled PDF, but it doesn't display the correct number in LyX.

Comment: @PaulRougieux Are you using LyX 2.3? As scottkosty said, the numbering will not be correct in older versions.

Comment: Torbjørn T. is right. Note also that 2.3.0 has not yet been released. If you are interested in testing 2.3.0rc2 (a test version that will not be too different from 2.3.0), we would be very interested in any feedback. But you should not use 2.3.0rc2 for serious work.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes I'm using Lyx V2.2.2. Thanks now I know why numbering doesn't display properly.

Comment: Is there a way to perform the resume using a local layout?

Comment: @AnthonyMacks Don't know. I guess maybe copy all the relevant code from the module file to the local layout, but I don't know if that works.