# Continued numbering throughout sections

Tags: numbering, exam

I would like to display:

```
I. Factor completely.

   1.  some polynomial

   2.  some other polynomial

II. Reduce each expression.

   3.  some rational expression

   4.  some other rational expression
```

But I would like to keep the numbering running throughout each section, so if I add another question to a section I don't have to re-number everything.  I know if I use `\begin{questions} \end{questions}` that I can do this, but then I can't insert the section number and the instructions.  Or at least, I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a list to create your questions, you can use the `resume` feature provided by `enumitem`, as cited in this question, [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{Factor completely}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item  some polynomial
  \item some other polynomial
\end{enumerate}
\section{Reduce each expression.}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item some rational expression
  \item some other rational expression
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (It seems we share an interest in questions involving the `enumitem` package, tonight! ;-)  I think it’s better to define a `series`, here, just in case some other, unrelated `enumerate` environment occurs in between.

Comment: Ahhhh....  "resume"!  Thanks so much!