# How to resume enumi in a question of exsheets?

Tags: counters, enumitem, exsheets

I can resume by adding `\setcounter{enumi}{\thetemp}` before the first item `\setcounter{temp}{\theenumi}` after the last item where `temp` is my new counter. However this approach does not look elegant. I don't want to type those adjustments by hand. Is there any better way to  inject those adjustments by patching?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
\begin{enumerate}[resume,label=\arabic*.]
    \item must be three rather than one.
    \item must be four rather than two.
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably due to the nested environments, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list for a possible solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want that the “subquestions” are numbered using the same series throughout the document, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\newcounter{globalenumerate}
\newenvironment{genumerate}
 {\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{\value{globalenumerate}}}
 {\setcounter{globalenumerate}{\value{enumi}}\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
\begin{genumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
\end{genumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
\begin{genumerate}
    \item must be three rather than one.
    \item must be four rather than two.
\end{genumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

This won't affect other usages of `enumerate`.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `series` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., series=A]%
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=A]
    \item must be three rather than one.
    \item must be four rather than two.
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Given that the OP wants to automate things as much as possible, you may want to add the instruction `\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*.,resume=A}` in the preamble, after loading the `enumitem` package. That way, the subsequent `[label=\arabic*., series=A]` and `[resume*=A]` option directives may be omitted.

Comment: @Mico: I already thought of this possibility, but what if only some questions have to share the same counter, another set of questions another counter, and so on?

Answer (score 5):

The `enumitem` package features a `resume` option, which you are attempting to employ. However, this option works only locally, i.e., not across other numbered environments. However, the package also features a method to make the resume feature apply globally; see section 3.5 of the package's user guide for the full details. The global form of `resume` differs from the local form of `resume` by making `resume` point to a "series". I suggest you create a dedicated enumerate-like environment (called, say, `myenum`) as follows:

```
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum]{label=\arabic*.,resume=xyz}
```

That way, you still have access to the "regular" `enumerate` environment elsewhere in the document.

A full MWE (I'll skip the screenshot):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum]{label=\arabic*.,resume=xyz}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
\begin{myenum}
    \item one
    \item two
\end{myenum}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
\begin{myenum}
    \item three
    \item four
\end{myenum}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```