# Several subsequent enumerate environments - How can one continue the counting?

Tags: enumerate, article

In an article, several sections have an `enumerate` environment. What is the easiest way to let the counter continue across all the different environments?

It is obviously possible to use

```
\begin{enumerate}   
\setcounter{enumi}{5}    % last item of previous enumerate
```

at the start of every subsequent environment, but then one has to change all these numbers in the subsequent environments whenever an item is added in some section. Is there a better, automatic and simple way to do this?

Comment: The `enumitem` package has a `resume` key for that.

Comment: This must be the record for answer speed - thank you!

Comment: Yes, it has been answered almost 10 lease ago. ;-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1669

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat can answer and not answer your question at the same time ... but you can never guess both his speed and position !

Comment: That exactly what  `linguex`  package does, but without using environments (easy typing).