# Latex numbering

Tags: numbering, itemize, enumitem

I want to create list like attached pic
[image]

I try this command

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item xxx
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
\item yy
\end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
```

But output is different. How to fix that?

Comment: I'd suggest you use the `enumitem` package. Using `\item [Xxx]` will get you the first level list. For the second level list you can use `\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*]` and for subsequent lists where you want the numbering to continue you need to indicate that the numbering is to continue: `\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*, resume*]`.

Comment: For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  A particular solution is often dependent on the packages that you are using.

Comment: Not sure if you intend the XXX/YYY/ZZZ to be item-like aligned or normal-text-like aligned, but in the latter case duplicate of [enumerate - Resuming a list - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[nosep]
\item[xxx]   \mbox{}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \end{enumerate}
\item[yy]   \mbox{}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item D
    \item E
    \end{enumerate}
\item[yy]   \mbox{}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item F
    \item G
    \item H
    \item I
    \end{enumerate}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But it can also be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\noindent%
xxx
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \end{enumerate}
yy
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item D
    \item E
    \end{enumerate}
zz  
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item F
    \item G
    \item H
    \item I
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]