# How to Realign an Unnumbered Enumerate Item

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate, justification

**UPDATE** This question is not a duplicate with [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list)

In this post, I am asking to align the text of an unnumbered enumerate item  directly under the previous (numbered) item and *not* under the last paragraph prior to the enumeration.

The answer given here follows   [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list), which, if run with the Latin text I post, does not align the unnumbered item under the [3.] as asked, but under the paragraph---which is not part of the enumeration.

Therefore, I respectfully ask that this question be reopened.

---

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\large
\lipsum[3]
\begin{enumerate}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\item Hic sunt quaedam verba. Hic sunt quaedam verba. Hic sunt quaedam verba. Hic sunt quaedam verba.
\item Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt.
\item Hic plura etiam verba sunt. Hic plura etiam verba sunt. Hic plura etiam verba sunt.
\item[] Quomodo haec verba sub align [3]. Quomodo haec verba sub align [3]. Quomodo haec verba sub align [3]. Quomodo haec verba sub align [3].
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I left justify the fourth (the non-numbered) item so that it is vertically aligned under the [3.]?

Thank you.

Comment: So you want the entire item `Quomodo haec...` to be shoved left, not just the first line of the item, correct?

Comment: @Werner To begin the Quomodo hace sentence as if it were `\item hace`---like the output that egreg just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what would be the typographical meaning of this.

Anyway, you can do it. But beware that such an alignment between items 9 and 10 would make no sense at all.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{unaligned}
 {%
  \par
  \sbox0{\labelenumi}%
  \leftskip=-\dimexpr\wd0+\labelsep\relax
 }
 {\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2][1-3]
\item \lipsum[3][1-3]
\item \lipsum[4][1-3]
\begin{unaligned}
\lipsum[5][1-4]
\end{unaligned}
\item \lipsum[6][1-3]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks egreg; this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to close enumerate before the paragraph, where you want `flushleft` and continue the next `enumerate` with the continuation order, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\large
\lipsum[3]
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hic sunt quaedam verba. Hic sunt quaedam verba. Hic sunt quaedam verba. Hic sunt quaedam verba.
\item Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt.
\item Hic plura etiam verba sunt. Hic plura etiam verba sunt. Hic plura etiam verba sunt.
\end{enumerate}
Quomodo haec verba sub align [3]. Quomodo haec verba sub align [3]. Quomodo haec verba sub align [3]. Quomodo haec verba sub align [3].
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item Hic sunt quaedam verba. Hic sunt quaedam verba. Hic sunt quaedam verba. Hic sunt quaedam verba.
\item Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt. Hic plura verba sunt.
\item Hic plura etiam verba sunt. Hic plura etiam verba sunt. Hic plura etiam verba sunt.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output will be as:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your post, but it does not answer the question asked: To align the unnumbered item directly under [3.].