# Where is the current indent of environments stored?

Tags: lists

I know that \marginwidth+\marginsep gives the effective left margin for body text, but what about the extra indent from nested environments (like lists)?

The idea was for an enviroment that 'escapes' the current margin going back to the 'initial' one. Like this:

```
  Body text
  *  Piece of list
     Other stuff inside the list

  My new stuff << THIS ONE
  <-> I need this length
     
     continues the list
  *  stuff
     ...
  Back to body text
```

If already there's a package much better but at least know how to find that value would be useful

Comment: While not answering this question maybe what you want is more simply achieved with [enumerate - Resuming a list - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list) or something similar

Comment: The indent is in \@totalleftmargin

Comment: I tried with enumitem [resume] but I needed a more general solution… \@totalleftmargin is what I needed. By the way is there a latex tech reference or something with these info?

Comment: `texdoc source2e`