# Is there a way to append to a itemized list?

Tags: lists, itemize

I create a

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
\end{itemize}

% Appending this itemize to the itemize above.
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 3
\end{itemize}
```

Is there a way to set a key-value pair to the first itemize so it can recognize the second itemize and append to it without starting a new list of bulletpoints? I am trying to make itemize more modular so I don't have all the bulletpoints on the same itemize section. I can add more to that itemize section in a separate file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See `\restartlist` from the enumitem package

Comment: An `itemize`-type list uses the same marker (say, `\textbullet`) for all items. Is there something particularly unusual about the marker you have in mind? Or are you maybe thinking of an `enumerate`-type list, whose list markers are arabic numbers (1, 2, ...), roman numbers (i, ii, ...), or alphabetic characters (a, b, ...)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1669/5764)

Comment: So you would like the output to be a single itemize list with three items in it?  Do you know when you're definitely going to be done appending?  Because the easiest approach would be to not have the `\end{itemize}\begin{itemize}` in the first place, and handle that elsewhere.  Could you elaborate a bit more on why you want this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `itemize` list it really doesn't matter because as pointed out in a comment, the same marker is used. However, it is quite simple to do this with an `enumerate` list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
\end{enumerate}

% Appending this itemize to the itemize above.
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
    \item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Using `resume*` versus `resume` ensures the same settings are used as with the previous list. See the `enumitem` package documentation for details.