# How do I change the `enumerate` list format to use letters instead of the default Arabic numerals?

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

I've seen documentation whereby an `\alph` command is put around the `\begin{enumerate}` somewhere, but I'm not entirely sure how that operates...

Comment: checkout [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11030/lyx-enumeration-style-from-numbers-to-letters), which gives more flexibility and also works in LyX.

Answer (score 376, accepted):

Without any package you could do it by redefining the command `\theenumi` for formatting the `enumi` counter. (Also `enumii`, etc., for nested lists.)

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Alph{enumi}}
```

inside the environment.... Or better, you could use a package like [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) which allows, e.g.,

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
...
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*]
\item this is item a
\item another item
\end{enumerate}
```

Use `\alph` for lowercase letters, `\Alph` for uppercase, etc. See the package documentation for more info.

Comment: I prefer to define it in once the preamble instead of for each enumerate list: `\setenumerate[0]{label=(\Alph*)}` this way the first enum counter (level 0) will get this style in the whole document. If would you later decide to change this numbering, there's just the preamble statement to adjust.

Comment: Using the first one produces a trailing period.

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133146/21607) for replacing the trailing period with parentheses, or otherwise changing the appearance of the label.

Comment: Maybe it is obvious, but one can also put [label=\Alph*)] to have labels A), B)...

Comment: Is there a reason not to simply say `\item[a)]` when you want a paren afterwards, for example?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Because then the numbering/lettering wouldn't be automatic?

Comment: Hello @frabjous. How can I get the greek alphabet as items? Thank you.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342498/problem-with-enumeration-using-greek-letters).

Comment: @frabjous I tried the code, but the problem is that also italian letters becomes greek letters. How can I fix it?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi They shouldn't. Try removing "greek" from the babel options. If you're still having trouble, post your own question with a minimal example showing the problem. I can't troubleshoot in a comment thread.

Answer (score 325):

Use the package [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
.
.
.
\begin{enumerate}[(a)] % (a), (b), (c), ...
\item
\end{enumerate}
.
.
.
\begin{enumerate}[a)] % a), b), c), ...
\item
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: That requires the enumerate package. That's fine too, though I prefer enumitem because it has more options.

Comment: It works with enumitem with the option shortlabels: `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}`

Comment: And package `enumitem` supersedes `enumerate`, thus is preferred in all contexts.

Comment: I had to include both the `enumerate` and the `enumitem` packages for this code to work as expected.

Answer (score 54):

With `enumitem` package, we can do as follow:

Preamble:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\subscript}[2]{$#1 _ #2$}
```

In document use:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\subscript{E}{{\arabic*}})]
    \item
    Generated by the $f*\tilde{g}$, where $f\in C_c(G)$, $g\in C_c(G)$;
    \item
    Generated by the $h*\tilde{h}$, where $h\in C_c(G)$;
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: Use `\subscript{E}{{\arabic*}}`. Otherwise, starting from the tenth item, the subscripts don't work properly (only the first digit will be subscripted).

Comment: Instead of putting an extra pair of brackets in `\subscript{E}{{\arabic*}}`, I would modify the macro definition: `\newcommand{\subscript}[2]{${#1}_{#2}$}`.

Answer (score 46):

Working example ([documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item one 
    \item two
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can set once and use it for the whole document?

Answer (score 11):

A solution with the package tasks by Clemens Niederberger (see also a more complete example at [How to make horizontal lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146306/how-to-make-horizontal-lists/324740#324740)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}


\bfseries Horizontal list: a = alphabetical \normalfont
\begin{tasks}[counter-format = {tsk[a].},label-offset = {0.6em},label-format = {\bfseries}](6)
\task One
\task Two
\task Three
\task Four
\task Five
\task Six
\task Seven
\task Eight
\task Nine
\task Ten
\end{tasks}
\vglue5mm

\bfseries Horizontal list: A = Alphabetical \normalfont
\begin{tasks}[counter-format = {(tsk[A])},label-offset = {0.8em},label-format = {\bfseries}](3)
\task One
\task Two
\task Three
\task Four
\task Five
\task Six
\task Seven
\task Eight
\task Nine
\task Ten
\end{tasks}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I was able to solve the problem with enumitem package.

From the documentation of enumitem:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

% if you want to create a new list from scratch
\newlist{alphalist}{enumerate}{1}
% in that case, at least label must be specified using \setlist
\setlist[alphalist,1]{label=\textbf{\alph*.}}

...

\begin{alphalist}
    \item Apple
    \item Orange
    \item Peach
\end{alphalist}
```

Answer (score 8):

Simple thing, yet people are using complex approach to solve it.
Simply use `[]` after `enumerate` command to define your numbering style as follows:

```
\begin{enumerate}[a.)] # for a.), b.), ...
    \item 
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}[(a.)] # for (a.), (b.), ...
    \item 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[1.] # for 1., 2., ...
    \item 
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}[(1.)] # for (1.), (2.), ...
    \item 
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}[(a)] # for (a), (b), ...
    \item 
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}[1.)] # for 1.), 2.), ...
    \item 
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}[i.)] # for i.), ii.), ...
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
```

etc.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! Nice as this would be to have in base LaTeX, it doesn't work without additional packages.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes I use `linguex` instead of the `enumerate`-like environments because the simple syntax list and because in not a closed environment,  so you can insert normal paragraphs or even start a new section and follow with the same list. Unfortunately, the documentation show some indications to change the label and the counter value, but not the counter style, so I hope this could help to someone.

The MWE how to *temporarily* change to an alphabetic uppercase label in a environment or to the default alphabetic lowercase style of the sublist as first level, without any environment (this approach is in the documentation), in both cases without change the main arabic list.

Note: using `linguex` the blank lines after the items matter, as well as the number of blank lines to return to normal text. In the MWE are changed by `\par` commands to avoid confusions at this respect.

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\newcounter{ExAl}
\setcounter{ExAl}{5} 
\newenvironment{Alist}{%
\let\ExAl\ExNo
\setcounter{ExNo}{0}
\renewcommand{\ExLBr}{}
\renewcommand{\ExRBr}{) }
\let\oldarabic\arabic
\let\arabic\Alph}{%
\let\arabic\oldarabic
\let\ExNo\ExAl}
\begin{document}
\ex. this is an item \par
\ex. another item\par
This is a normal paragraph  
\begin{Alist}
    \ex. this is an item\par  
    \ex. another item\par
    This is a normal paragraph\par  
    \ex. one more item !\par
\end{Alist}
This is a normal paragraph  
\ex. this is item a\par
\ex. another item\par
This is a normal paragraph\par  
\a. this is an item
\b. another item
\b. one more item\par
This is a normal paragraph\par  
\ex. this is item a\par
\ex. another item\par
This is a normal paragraph\par  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy trick:

```
 \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
 \item first
 \item second
 \item third
 \end{enumerate}
```

But it only works when you use `\usepackage{enumerate}`.

Comment: This worked for me, and doesn't require an external package to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `enumerate` package easier to use.

```
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item 
.
.
.
\end{enumerate}
```

For alphabets, use `\begin{enumerate}[(a)]`. Easy?