# LyX enumeration style from numbers to letters

Tags: lyx, enumerate

I'd like to use, for this specific instance, letter style enumeration [ like a) b) c) ] . I realize that I can nest one enumerate environment in another and the style will change, but I don't want a dangling "1." from the topmost enumerate environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write into `Document->Settings->Preamble`:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate{label=A)}
\setenumerate[2]{label=a)}
```

For deeper values use also [3], [4]. Inside LyX you will still see the 1. If you want to change this too, then you'll have to rewrite your LyX layout file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to have these settings apply to a specific enumerate environment? For example, in one part of the document I want the highest level symbol to be letters, and in another part of the document I want the highest level symbol to be numbers.

Comment: yes @Gus, see [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11030/lyx-enumeration-style-from-numbers-to-letters/213344#213344). you'll need to use `\renewcommand` repeatedly.

Answer (score 24):

## Short answer

- To get `a)`, add this to the preamble: `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}`
- To get `[a]`, add this to the preamble: `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{[\alph{enumi}]}`

If you don't want the change to occur **globally**, then add this code right before the enumeration (and resotre right after, if needed).

## Long answer

In the preamble, use the `\renewcommand{indicator}{format}` syntax for each level of heirarchy you would like to change (4 level max. are supported), where *indicator* is either of the following **label indicators**:

1. `\labelenumi` -- 1st level
2. `\labelenumii` -- 2nd level
3. `\labelenumiii` -- 3rd level
4. `\labelenumiv` -- 4th level

and *format* is a macro consisting of **enumerators** and **styles**.

The style can be any of the following:

- `\arabic{enumerator}`, for 1, 2, 3, ...
- `\alph{enumerator}`, for a, b, c, ...
- `\Alph{enumerator}`, for A, B, C, ...
- `\roman{enumerator}`, for i, ii, iii, ...
- `\Roman{enumerator}`, for I, II, III, ...

The enumerator can be any of the following:

1. `enumi` -- 1st level
2. `enumii` -- 2nd level
3. `enumiii` -- 3rd level
4. `enumiv` -- 4th level

I personally prefer the `1.4.2 a)` repeating format, for which you need:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\labelenumii\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\alph{enumiv})}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can set custom labels for individual items:

1. Use the default "Numbered list" environment in LyX (select from the menu or use the keyboard shortcut ^P E).
2. Insert a "Custom Item" inset: Open the context menu via
   Ctrl+click/right click over a list element and select "Custom Item".
3. In the Custom Item inset, enter a custom label for this particular item.

You will see the default labels in LyX, but the output will use the label from the "Custom Item" box. In LyX:

```
1. Custom Item[A] Fruits:

a) Custom Item[A.1] orange

b) Custom Item[A.2] apple
```

will produce in the output file:

A Fruits:

A.1 orange

A.2 apple

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I do not understand this answer. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

These answers are all quite old, and Lyx has moved on, adding a module named Customisable Lists (enumitem). The User's Guide indicates how to use it, but in short: if you want to change the behavior of just one enumeration, add the module in the document settings, and then, at the beginning of your list, Insert->Enumerate Options. In ERT write

```
label=\roman{enumi}.
```

or however you'd like to format the label. Done! and once you've finished this enumeration, the others will be according to the usual style.

Comment: Thanks, @John. I just didn't get it first, that I needed to go to Document -> Settings -> Modules and add the "Customisable Lists (enumitem)". Otherwise there is no "Insert->Enumerate Options" menu item.

Answer (score 1):

in preamble

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii.}
```