# How to change enumerate item from 1. to (1)?

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

I would like to force latex enumerate environment to output (1), (2),... in place of 1., 2. that he gives by default. How could I do this ?

I don't need to do it in my whole document but in some places only. Hence I should only make modifications in the chosen enumerate environment.

Comment: Not totally the answer, but should give you a good hint

Comment: @darthbith Thanks. The link you provided answered my question. I posted it as an answer. Should I delete my question?

Comment: This is not totally a duplicate, only here I've found how to avoid trailing periods in custom list numbering.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't require loading a separate package (such as `enumerate` or `enumitem`): Just issue the command

```
\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}
```

in a TeX group, before `\begin{enumerate}`. (To make the scope of `\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}` global, place the instruction in the preamble.)

Here's the output of an MWE that also shows how one may cross-reference enumerated items:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A first item.  \label{item:1}
\item A second item. \label{item:2}
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup
\noindent
Here are some cross-references to items \ref{item:1} and \ref{item:2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll keep it in mind but here I only need to do this on one list in my whole document so I can't use this solution

Comment: @mwoua -- If it's only one enumerated list in the entire document for which the labels need to be changed to (1), (2), etc., you could write `{ \renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}` (note the presence of the left curly brace) immediately before the list in question and `}` after the list. Doing so will limit the scope of the redefinition of `\labelenumi` to the group defined by the pair of curly braces.

Comment: I found the following significantly easier to implement, simply add `[label=(\arabic*)]` after `\begin{enumerate}`.

Comment: @AlexanderHepburn - Thanks. I actually fully agree! :-) But please note the age of my answer -- it's *more than 8 years old* by now -- and that I was careful to write that it was "a solution that doesn't require loading a separate package". Not sure if, back then, the `enumitem` package had the functionality to recognize the option `label=(\arabic*)`...

Answer (score 26):

Finally I found what I was looking for

```
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[{(1)}]
\item 
.
.
.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Notice you can also just use ```[(1)]``` instead of ```[{(1)}]```.

Comment: I get an error of the form Package enumitem Error: (1) undefined   @ViktorGlombik    \begin{enumerate}[(1)] also does not work

Comment: @HaoS use the package enumerate instead of enumitem

Comment: This works for me `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]`