# inline and vertical enumeration in the same document

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, vertical-alignment, enumerate, enumitem

I want to implement both inline and vertical enumeration in my document. I know that inline enumeration can be achieved using `inline` option of `enumitem` package.

In addition, I found this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146306/how-to-make-horizontal-lists) (second answer)in which a custom inline list environment is defined.

However, I do not fully understand how to define my own list environment in which the items are presented horizontally, without affecting the vertical behavior of the enumerate environment.

Let's say that I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Items will be presented vertically
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[inline,label=(\roman*)]
\item Items will be presented horizontially
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are not loading `enumitem`,  also with `enumitem ` inline listed are labeled with a *, please see the manual

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @daleif already mentioned in the comment if you load the `enumitem` package with the `inline` option the starred versions of the environments `itemize`, `enumerate` and `description` are defined. You can then use these to get a horizontal enumeration.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Items will be presented vertically
\item Items will be presented vertically
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Items will be presented horizontially
\item Items will be presented horizontially
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

---

**Output:**

[image: enumitem]