# How to indent the items which are in a line?

Tags: indentation, itemize

My aim was to make horizontal lists and followed this question(**See the answer from @SDrolet**): [How to make horizontal lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146306/how-to-make-horizontal-lists?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

And now I have the following (**UPDATE**)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[counter-format={(tsk[r])}, label-align=left, label-offset={10mm}, label-width={10mm}, label-format={\bfseries}](2)
    \task Robotics
    \task Remote Sensing
    \task Bio-medical Applications
    \task Military Applications
    \task Equipment Monitoring      and Diagnostics
    \task Transportation Systems
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the result(see:-item: `Equipment Monitoring and Diagnostics` which is not intended properly):

[image]

I would like to inden the item `(V)` as follows:

```
 (V) Equipment Monitoring
     and Diagnostics
```

How to make the proper indentation in this case?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @samcarter Could you please tell me, what is not clear from the question?

Comment: With `\documentclass{article}` and using package `tasks` I couldn't reproduce your problem. You should probably play with `label-offset` and `label-width`. Though if you post a MWE, a compilable code showing your problem, you can get more help

Comment: Not everyone know where `talks` come from. You are much much more likely to get help if you provide a minimal but full example that others can just copy and test as is. Then it is also a lot easier for others to pinpoint the problem and provide suggestions. As your question sits now, users trying to help have to provide 2/3 of a document you test it.

Comment: @JeJo It would be easier to help you, if we could reproduce the problem and don't have to guess which packages you might or might not use.

Comment: @samcarter I have updated the code with packages. Sorry for not including it before.

Comment: @bmv I have updated the code with packages. Sorry for not including it before.

Comment: @daleif I have updated the code with packages. Sorry for not including it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the change to `label-offset` the text lines are aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tasks}



\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[
counter-format={(tsk[r])}, 
label-align=left, 
label-width=1.9em,
label-format={\bfseries}
](2)
    \task Robotics
    \task Remote Sensing
    \task Bio-medical Applications
    \task Military Applications
    \task Equipment Monitoring \par and Diagnostics
    \task Transportation Systems
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are two csolutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[counter-format={(tsk[r])}, label-align=left, label-offset={10mm}, label-width={10mm}, label-format={\bfseries}](2)
    \task Robotics
    \task Remote Sensing
    \task Bio-medical Applications
    \task Military Applications
    \task \parbox[t]{4cm}{\RaggedRight Equipment Monitoring and Diagnostics}
    \task Transportation Systems
\end{tasks}

\begin{tasks}[counter-format={(tsk[r])}, label-align=left, label-width={10mm}, label-format={\bfseries}, item-indent =20mm ](2)
    \task Robotics
    \task Remote Sensing
    \task Bio-medical Applications
    \task Military Applications
    \task Equipment Monitoring and Diagnostics
    \task Transportation Systems
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]