# Listing \enumerate numbering style to the right

Tags: lists, enumerate

Is it possible to make \enumerate items listed to the right?
If I try the MWE as follow:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{makeidx}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{enumerate}  
    \item Annie: May I borrow your new novel?\\  
     Lee: Yes, but next Monday, I............reading it by then  

\begin{enumerate}  

        \item would finish          \item will have finishing  
        \item will be finishing     \item am finished  
        \item have finished  
\end{enumerate}  

\end{enumerate}  
\end{document}
```

the `\item` lists is go downward as always have to be.
I need my enumerated numbering style like this:

a. item 1               b. item 2             c. item 3   d. item 4
 e. item 5

Comment: You might want to use the `enumitem` package with its `inline` option as explained here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146311/134144

Comment: The enumerate package also has a [label=\alph] option, assuming you really do what a,b,c...  Alternatively, `renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alpha{enumi}}` although several packages use different counters than enumi, enumii, ...