# How to enumerate items inline?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

I have to make the list look exactly like this (Cyrillic letters are not the problem). Could you please help me.[image]

Comment: \usepackage[inline]{enumitem} and `\begin{enumerate*}\end{enumerate*}` (with asterisks) should do your work.

Comment: the text just states a math problem, which I have to rewrite in my homework.

Comment: @JairoADelRio what if I already have ```\usepackage{enumitem}``` in the document? just substitute and it won't break other lists?

Comment: Yeah, just add [inline] and use the starred environment when you need inline enumerations (normal enumerations still work)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make horizontal lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146306/how-to-make-horizontal-lists)

Comment: @JairoADelRio you have already answered it, I was just testing. You can submit your answer so that I can close the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[How to make horizontal lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146306/how-to-make-horizontal-lists)

```
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{enumerate*} % Add * for inline items
\item
\item
\end{enumerate*}
```