# Disable newline when using enumerate

Tags: enumerate

Could you tell me please, how to disable the transition to a new line when I use enumerate ? I need to do it as in the picture. For No1, I do not use enumerate but for “a” and “b”, I use enumerate
[image]

Comment: Take a look at the inline option that is available when using the enumitem package.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146311/134144

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything worked out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make horizontal lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146306/how-to-make-horizontal-lists)