# Justify a Horizontal List

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, enumitem

I want to justify a horizontal list. I'm able to get a horizontal list but I want to have it justified horizontally. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize*}
    \item Advanced Data Science
    \item Machine Learning
    \item Deep Learning
    \item Computer Vision
\end{itemize*}
\end{document}
```

• Advanced Data Science • Machine Learning • Deep Learning • Computer Vision            | End of empty space

I want this justified:

• Advanced Data Science    • Machine Learning    • Deep Learning    • Computer Vision

Anyone have any idea?

Edit: Added a reproducible example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the keys `itemjoin` and `itemjoin*`, as in:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize]{itemjoin=\hspace*{\fill},itemjoin*=\hspace*{\fill}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize*}
    \item Advanced Data Science
    \item Machine Learning
    \item Deep Learning
    \item Computer Vision
\end{itemize*}

\begin{itemize*}
    \item A
    \item M
    \item D
    \item C
\end{itemize*}

\end{document}
```

For even positioning, have a look into e.g. [How to make horizontal lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146306/how-to-make-horizontal-lists)

Comment: This seems to not have a sapce before the last bullet.  Also, why the `landscape` option?

Comment: @PeterGrill as you probably noticed, Kevin did not provide a full MWE, therefore I had to made assumptions. And thanks for the hint, I adjusted `itemjoin*`

Comment: I don't want to manually insert the spacing, as I may have to add another item. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: @KevinM it is done, automatically, try it for yourself, you can add as many items as you like and they all carry the spacing. Or do you mean, that I used the options only for this `itemize*` environment? I adjusted it and use `\setlist` now, is that what you want?
In general, your question could have been formulated clearer and for the next time, please provide a MWE!

Comment: No I mean the command "\hspace*{2em}" . Sorry if I'm not being clear. I don't mind whether it's for the entire document or not. I have to change it to 5em to get it justified. Otherwise there's extra spacing to the right. I don't wish to do this :(

Also adding an item `\item Data Structure `adds it onto the next line.

Comment: Sorry @KevinM but it would be best if you draw a clear picture of what you really want to achieve. If you want to auto fill the space, try `\setlist[itemize]{itemjoin=\hspace*{\fill},itemjoin*=\hspace*{\fill}}` but this will not prevent the line break, if a line is full, it is full. So maybe you start from scratch with a simple drawing to illustrate what you want and in which cases.

Comment: \fill worked perfectly! Agreed that it would not break the line break but there are ways around that. I'll edit your post and accept it as final answer

Comment: @KevinM thanks!