# Horizontal lists with ConTeXt

Tags: lists, enumerate, context

What is the ConTeXt equivalent of `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}`?

See: [How to make horizontal lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146306/how-to-make-horizontal-lists)

I have read https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/_setupitemgroup without finding what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `text` option.

You can set it for a single list:

```tex
\startTEXpage
    Before text
    \startitemize[A, text]
        \item One
        \item Two
        \item Three
    \stopitemize
    after text.
\stopTEXpage
```

[image: output]

Or for all lists of a certain type:

```tex
\setupitemize[1][n][style=ssbf]
\setupitemize[2][text, KR]

\startTEXpage
    \startitemize
        \item \startitemize
            \item One
            \item Two
            \item Three
        \stopitemize
        \item \startitemize
            \item Four
            \item Five
            \item Six
        \stopitemize
        \item \startitemize
            \item Seven
            \item Eight
            \item Nine
        \stopitemize
    \stopitemize
\stopTEXpage
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you, do you know if there is a way to remove the parentheses?

Comment: @richardIII When using the `text` key, you can get rid of the parentheses by `\setupitemize[2][text,KR][lefttext=,righttext=]`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks