# How to change itemize bullets with specific alphabet?

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

I have an itemize bullets in beamer as follow:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Condition 1
    \item Condition 2
    \item Condition 3
\end{itemize}
```

which produces as you know a list of bullets:

> - Condition 1
> - Condition 2
> - Condition 3

What I want is to replace the bullets by C1, C2 and C3 as the following:

> C1 Condition 1
>
> C2 Condition 2
>
> C3 Condition 3

Of course I look for an answer before and based on [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229156/56788), I did the following:

```
\begin{itemize}[label=(C)]
    \item Condition 1
    \item Condition 2
    \item Condition 3
\end{itemize}
```

but I got an error message `! Use of \beamer@parseitem doesn't match its definition.`

The way I did it "correctly" is as follow:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item[] C1 Condition 1
    \item[] C2 Condition 2
    \item[] C3 Condition 3
\end{itemize}
```

but it looks ugly to me. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`description`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Description) environment.

```
\begin{description}
    \item[C1] Condition 1
    \item[C2] Condition 2
    \item[C3] Condition 3
\end{description}
```

[image]

If you have a lot of these or think you might reorder them, it may be easier to modify `enumerate`'s behavior, so that they're numbered automatically.

```
\begin{enumerate}[\bf C1]
    \item Condition 1
    \item Condition 2
    \item Condition 3
\end{enumerate}
```

This has the same output.

Comment: You don't need to load enumerate, beamer does it already.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thanks! I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[C1] % or \begin{enumerate}[<+->][C1] for overlays
    \item Condition 1
    \item Condition 2
    \item Condition 3
\end{enumerate} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In a 'limited' sense `enumitem` and `beamer` can work together, if a real numeration is used, then `enumerate` is the better environment, not `itemize`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={C\arabic*}]
    \item Condition 1
    \item Condition 2
    \item Condition 3
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: enumitem will break the overlays.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: ` \item<1->` etc. works

Comment: Well I wouldn't use enumitem with beamer, to fragile for my liking. E.g. if I remove the optional argument in your example, I get a `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].` error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is right. I also suffer from same problem now.

Comment: @inmybrain: That's why I wrote 'in a limited sense' ;-)

Comment: enumitem broke my beamer itemize format setup. I partially fixed it before giving up and using @Ulrike Fischer's answer instead