# How to enumerate questions alphabetically

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

Is there a method like {enumerate}, but which can enumerate questions in alphabetic order, As in the list in Question 2 in the image below.

[image]

I tried something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\section{}
\subsection{}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting partial screenshots it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: In addition to what @Andrew said, it's also really unclear what you actually want the output to be.  Are you simply asking for lettered enumerations? If so, this is a duplicate of [How do I change the \`enumerate\` list format to use letters instead of the default Arabic numerals?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2291). Or are you asking how to use letters for section numbers?

Comment: Hi! @Andrew I am new to LaTeX, so I don't know \documentclass are that important. I have updated the picture. Thank you guys a lot

Comment: @StewieGriffin I've removed the image of your code: instead of posting screen shots from your editor, you should add the actual code to the question. You can format it as code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here you go. It is easier if you use `\usepackage{enumitem}`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item This is (a)
    \item And this would be (b)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]