# How do I change the labels of enumerate?

Tags: enumerate

I have the following list:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Particle Synthesis
    \item Video analysis
    \item Temperature Calibration
    \item Video Demonstration
\end{enumerate}
```

Which gives me a list enumerated by numericals (1., 2., ,...).
Could someone advise me how to add an 'S' in front of each label (S1., S2., ...) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [How do I change the `enumerate` list format to use letters instead of the default Arabic numerals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/how-do-i-change-the-enumerate-list-format-to-use-letters-instead-of-the-defaul)

You can use : `\renewcommand{\theenumi}{S\arabic{enumi}}`

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{ % create a group so the change is local 
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{S\arabic{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Particle Synthesis
    \item Video analysis
    \item Temperature Calibration
    \item Video Demonstration
\end{enumerate}
}
\noindent Let's see a subsequent enumerate.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Particle Synthesis
    \item Video analysis
    \item Temperature Calibration
    \item Video Demonstration
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

I wanted to point that, while redefining `\theenumi` is fine in most cases, the situation can be more complex if the counter  is prefixed with a longer text, as  by default the label of an enumerate environment is right-aligned at a fixed distance of the text leftmargin (`\leftmargini` here) and it can overflow into the leftmargin.

A better solution for this case is to use the versatile package `enumitem`. Demo:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{SSS\,\arabic{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Particle Synthesis
    \item Video analysis
    \item Temperature Calibration
    \item Video Demonstration
\end{enumerate}

\noindent With \texttt{enumitem}:
\begin{enumerate}[label=SSS\,\arabic*, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
    \item Particle Synthesis
    \item Video analysis
    \item Temperature Calibration Temperature Calibration Temperature Calibration Temperature Calibration
    \item Video Demonstration
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As your example shows, this package is great, e.g. in removing the otherwise automatic added trailing dot -- as you can see in the first part of your example. Output: `SSS 1.`, whereas you only defined: `SSS\,\arabic{enumi}` (without any trailing dot!).