# How to enumerate from i, then j, k, l, m,

Tags: enumerate

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This would result in numbering (i), (ii), (iii), ... 
I want to number (i), (j), (k), ... What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I change the `enumerate` list format to use letters instead of the default Arabic numerals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2291/134144)

Comment: with the enumitem package instead of enumerate: `\begin{enumerate}[start=9,label=(\alph*)]`.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]\setcounter{enumi}{8}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

That `8` is there because the letter “i” is the 9<sup>th</sup> letter of the alphabet.

Comment: *That 8 is there because the letter “i” is the 9th letter of the alphabet.* ah yes perfect sense

Answer (score 2):

Using `enumitem` rather than `enumerate` is recommended. You can even avoid to count the letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \intfromalph \int_from_alph:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),start=\intfromalph{i}]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]