# Custom Options with \enumerate or alternatives

Tags: numbering, enumerate

I would like an enumerate-type environment where I specify a letter "say G" and list has the form (G1), (G2), (G3), etc. Is this something I can do with \begin{enumerate} or is there a simple way to create such lists?

Comment: Use [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) with the option `label=(G\arabic*)`. See [How do I change the `enumerate` list format to use letters instead of the default Arabic numerals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2291/5764) (related).