# Begin enumerate from zero in LyX beamer

Tags: beamer, lyx

I am making a presentation using beamer in LyX. Is it possible to have a numbered list (enumerate) starting with zero (0) instead of one (1)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make an enumerate list start at something other than 1?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142/how-can-i-make-an-enumerate-list-start-at-something-other-than-1)

Comment: Hi Marco... Sorry I am not very good with latex. Is there a simple way to do this in LyX?

Comment: Sorry I have no experiences with LyX. I don't like LyX (Sorry). Of course LaTeX needs a big induction but after you can manipulate everything very simple.

Comment: a related ticket for LyX now exists: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11098

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `beamer` I don't have any very good ideas, but there are at least two options.

### Specify the first item label manually, and set counter

Write your list, and at the start of the first item add an ERT, where you write

```
[0.]\setcounter{enumi}{0}
```

This way you override the automatic item label, replacing it with `0.`, and then you reset the counter to zero, so the next item is numbered 1.

[image]

### Write the entire list in an ERT

Add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and write the list code as demonstrated by Jubobs in his answer, or in the question linked to by Marco Daniel.

[image]

### Standard classes

For the standard classes, you can do this by using the `enumitem` package via a module: Document --> Settings --> Modules, add the *Customisable lists (enumitem)*  module.

[image]

In the document, create your list, then right click the first element and choose *Insert Short Title*. Finally, in the `opt` box that appears, write `start=0`:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the very detailed response, Torbjørn.

Comment: The `Beamer` document class does not allow `enumitem` to be used. A workaround I found is to write `[]\addtocounter{enumi}{5}` in the ERT at the beginning of the list. This creates an empty list item; the next item starts with the desired number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the blue circled style common in beamer presentations, you have to define the following command:

```latex
\newcommand{\labelname}[1]{
    \def\insertenumlabel{#1}%
    \usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}%
}
```

Then you can use it like this:
[image: screenshot of how to use in lyx]

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277057/167579).