# LaTeX Beamer: Enumerate with manual numbers

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I'd like to do the following enumeration in beamer;

```
1. First Item
2. Second Item
3. Third Item
3'. Alternative Version of Third Item.
```

However, if I do this:

```
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \item Third Item
    \item[3'] Alternative Third Item
  \end{enumerate}
```

then the last item doesn't appear with the usual bullet style.

[image]

Help? 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'alternative' item? An overlay?

Comment: `\item[something]` is exactly the command to replace the 'standard' bullet

Comment: I just want the next item numbered with "3'" instead of "4", but I would like to keep the enumeration style.

Comment: Thank you Christian but I would also like to keep the formatting of the bullets. Just doing \item[3'] doesn't do it (see picture above). It's in latex beamer.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84166/itemize-bullets-without-itemization

Answer (score 6):

The following solution is independent of the theme used and will always produced the appropriate format for the items in the first level of `enumerate` (the `minipage`s in the example are just for brevity and are not relevant for the solution):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\Pitem{%
  \addtocounter{enumi}{-1}%
  \renewcommand\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}'}%
  \item%
  \renewcommand\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\item Second.
\item Third.
\Pitem Third prime.
\item Fourth.
\item Fifth.
\item Sixth.
\Pitem Sixth prime.
\item Seventh.
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[square]
\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\Pitem First prime.
\item Second.
\item Third.
\item Fourth.
\Pitem Fourth prime.
\item Fifth.
\item Sixth.
\item Seventh.
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `\Pitem` for the item(s) that will be "primed".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the same style for the bullet, but would like to change its label, you can use the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newcommand{\labelname}[1]{
    \def\insertenumlabel{#1}%
    \usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item first
        \item[\labelname{1'}] prime
        \item second
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The above code results in

[image: Generated output]

Answer (score 1):

I copied the bullet format, but I just faked the itemize format.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1]% #1 = text inside bullet
{
  \par\vspace{3pt}\hspace*{-15pt}%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
    {\pgftransformscale{1.75}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
    {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
      \pgftext{\usebeamerfont*{item projected}#1}}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
  \hspace{1pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item first
  \myitem{1'} alternate
  \item second
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: enumerate]