# Beamer: Custom numbers enumeration

Tags: beamer, numbering, enumerate

I want to allow custom numbering of examples in Beamer. In particular, I want to be able to have lists like the following (and I want to be able to use prime superscripts potentially for any number on a list):

1. Example 1.
2. Example 2.
   2’. Example 2.

I’m using a suggestion made by `timothymctim` here: `[LaTeX Beamer: Enumerate with manual numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161301/latex-beamer-enumerate-with-manual-numbers/277057#277057)', namely:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

    \newcommand{\labelname}[1]{
    \def\insertenumlabel{#1}%
\usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item first
    \item[\labelname{1'}] prime
    \item second
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Unlike `timothymctim`, I want to use the default theme, not `Warsaw`. However, when I use default theme, the custom numbered bullet point is not properly indented; it is misaligned relative to other numbers on the list. How can I control for this?

Answer (score 3):

The label is properly aligned but on the right side and not on the left. A compromise could be to align it on both sides by moving the prime on top of the period.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newlength{\primewidth}
\settowidth{\primewidth}{'}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item first
    \item[1'\hskip-\primewidth .] prime
    \item second
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To ignore the with of the prime, you can use a right overlap (`\rlap`):

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item first
    \item[1\rlap{'}.] prime
    \item second
\end{enumerate}
```

As mentioned by @samcarter, the use of `\labelname` is not strictly necessary here. However, it might still be useful if you use something different from the default `enumerate items` theme: in that case, use `\labelname{1\rlap{'}}` (note that the `.` is now omitted).

Comment: That's a clever solution! But is the `\labelname` necessary in this case? Wouldn't `\item[1.\rlap{'}] prime` give the desired result?

Comment: @samcarter Thanks, although it's about the same solution as yours, albeit a bit shorter. You're right about the `\labelname`: If you use `default` for `enumerate items`, you can just use `\item[1\rlap{'}.]`