# Interruption 'enumerate' list

Tags: enumerate

How do I put text in the 'enumerate' list by the inserted text can not be numbered, and that the bulleted list is not interrupted?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you want. Can you provide an example. Perhaps it would be more clear of what you're looking for.

Comment: You can make two separate lists with text in between. When starting the second enumerate set the starting value according to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142.

Comment: `\item[] some text here`?....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `enumitem` package defines a `resume`option, with this syntax:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
…
\begin{document}
\item
\item
…
\end{enumerate}

Some  text. Some text. Some  text. Some text. Some  text. Some text. Some  text. Some text.

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item
…
\end{enumerate}
```

The `resume*` option uses the options of the previous enumerate environment

Answer (score 3):

This enables more packages for list. One of them is `mdwlist` which use the following syntax:

```
    \begin{enumerate}
\item   text
\item   text
    \suspend{enumerate}
some texts between enumerating
    \resume{enumerate}
\item   text
\item   text
\item   text
    \end{enumerate}
```

of course, in preamble of your document you should add

```
\usepackage{mdwlist}
```

Comment: Isn't mdwlist incompatible with several other packages? There is one of these older packages that has some issues.

Comment: Till to now I didn't observe any problems with it. I liked it because to my opinion has more logical syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the counter `enumi` that is used to number the bullets. By setting `\setcounter{enumi}{2}` the next bullet will have number 3, since it is increased before display. To get an automated system you can define your own counter where you save the value between two occurances of `enumerate`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{TMPenumnbr}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First bullet
\item Second bullet
\setcounter{TMPenumnbr}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{\value{TMPenumnbr}}
\item Third bullet
\item Fourth bullet
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]