# counters in theenumi 2

Tags: fonts, macros, fontspec, counters

I have the following MWE using `counters`. At which place can I insert `\stepcounter` to increase always at the next `\enumerate` item?
All positions which I've tried have failed with `\endcsname` error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\ngg{NewGardiner}


\newcounter{nw}
\setcounter{nw}{13000}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\ngg\symbol{"\the\value{\stepcounter{nw}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item rozhodovat se na hraně zajímavého
\item vždycky to tam máš (data v matematice)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try loading package  `enumitem` and use `\begin{enumerate}[label=\ngg\symbol{\theenumi}]` (if this is a first level list).

Comment: @Bernard I need to set the initial value to 13000. And this doesn't work for me: \usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}[\setcounter{theenumi}{13000} label=\ngg\symbol{\theenumi}]
  \item rozhodovat se na hraně zajímavého
  \item vždycky to tam máš (data v matematice)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

Comment: Probably [How can I make an enumerate list start at something other than 1?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142/134144) helps

Comment: You can use the key `start=13000`.

Comment: You do not want to start at  13000 decimal you want to start at hex 13000 which is `77824` or `"13000` also you don't want `NewGardiner` as that is the font which does _not_ have the hieroglyphs in Unicode positions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So which font if not NewGardiner ?

Comment: as I commented on one of your earlier questions the page you linked to showed two versions of that font the old one (that you have) which pre-dates these characters being in Unicode and a new one called something like NewGardiner-SSP, I forget exactly, which has the characters in Unicode order.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%I don't have this font and you want teh updated verison with Unicode ordering.
%\newfontfamily\ngg{NewGardiner} 
\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}

%you do not need a counter and want to start from 77824 not 13000
%\newcounter{nw}
%\setcounter{nw}{13000}

%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\ngg\symbol{"\the\value{\stepcounter{nw}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[start="13000,label={\ngg\symbol{\value{enumi}}}]
\item rozhodovat se na hraně zajímavého
\item vždycky to tam máš (data v matematice)
\item zzz
\item zzz
\item zzz
\item zzz
\item zzz
\item zzz
\item zzz
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Forks fine. Actually I need to subtract "13000 from the other occurence of the counter enumi as given here: `label=\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}'. How do I do this in XeTeX? This doesn't work:  label=\roman{enumi-13000}--\arabic{enumi-13000} One counter is supposed to be for Hieroglyphs and the other for roman and arabic and these latter two begin at 1 not at 13000.

Comment: leave start as the default 1 and use `label=\roman{enumi}--{\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+\value{enumi}}}`. and it will print the decimal value as well as a hieroglyph