# Make defined enumerate list start at something other than one without changing the definition

Tags: tables, lists, enumerate, ragged2e

I need to start my enumerate list start from 3. I use the enumeration on a table and giving newlist at the preamble. I've read [how-can-i-make-an-enumerate-list-start-at-something-other-than-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142/how-can-i-make-an-enumerate-list-start-at-something-other-than-1), but the solution is not working on my case. And since the new environment is created for tables, i wish you help me without changing the definition on the preamble. Or at least not giving affect when i implement it on the table. Your help is needed. Thanks in advance!

Here's the MWE (I'm not including the table):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem,array,ragged2e}

\newlist{ColEnum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[ColEnum,1]{label = \arabic*), left = 0pt, nosep, 
    before= {\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
        after = {\end{minipage}}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\endgraf\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{ColEnum}[left= 0pt, label=\arabic*), noitemsep, topsep= 0pt]
        \setcounter{enumi}{2}
        \item ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM
        \item ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM
    \end{ColEnum}
\vspace{1cm}
    \begin{ColEnum}[left= 0pt, label=\arabic*), noitemsep, topsep= 0pt]
        \addtocounter{enumi}{2}
        \item ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM
    \item ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM
    \end{ColEnum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since your custom environment is called ColEnum, try \setcounter{ColEnumi}{2} instead of setcounter{enumi}{2}. See also page 17 of the enumitem package manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter to use is `ColEnumi`. When you do

```
\newlist{foo}{<level>}
```

`enumitem` defines counters `fooi`, `fooii` and so on up to the specified `<level>`. In your case just `ColEnumi`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem,ragged2e}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newlist{ColEnum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[ColEnum,1]{
  label = \arabic*),
  left = 0pt,
  nosep, 
  before = {\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}\RaggedRight},
  after = {\end{minipage}},
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{ColEnum}
  \setcounter{ColEnumi}{2}
  \item ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM
  \item ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM
\end{ColEnum}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`enumitem` defines the `start`key:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem,array,ragged2e}

\newlist{ColEnum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[ColEnum,1]{label = \arabic*), left = 0pt, nosep,
    before= {\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
        after = {\end{minipage}}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\endgraf\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \noindent
    \begin{ColEnum}[left= 0pt, label=\arabic*), start=15,noitemsep, topsep= 0pt]
        \setcounter{enumi}{2}
        \item ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM
        \item ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM
    \end{ColEnum}
\vspace{1cm}
    \begin{ColEnum}[left= 0pt, label=\arabic*), start=314, noitemsep, topsep= 0pt]
        \item ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM
    \item ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM ITEM
    \end{ColEnum}

\end{document}
```

[image]