# How can I enumerate with Roman numerals not starting with "(i)?"

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

I need an enumerated list that starts with `(iii)` instead of `(i)`. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried the suggestions from a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142/how-can-i-make-an-enumerate-list-start-at-something-other-than-1) but I still don't know how to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: enumitem and the start option

Comment: Ooh - now I'd like my Roman enumerated lists to start (), (i), (ii), ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `enumitem` package,

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Default style
\begin{enumerate}
  \item first
  \item second
\end{enumerate}

Roman numbering starting with three
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*., start=3]
  \item first
  \item second
\end{enumerate}

Configured format of item label
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), start=3]
  \item first
  \item second
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]